# Cannot set default function closure

Tags: rust, closures

I am trying to create a method that takes an `Option<impl Fn() -> ()>` as a parameter, and, if this parameter is `Some(func)`, stores `func` as a closure, but, if it is `None`, stores some default function as the closure. Specifically, my code is as follows:

```rust
fn foo() 
{
    println!("HI");
}

fn bar(baz: Option<impl Fn () -> ()>)
{
    let func = match baz {
        Some(func) => func,
        //None => foo,
        None => unimplemented!()
    };

    func();
}

pub fn main() {
    bar(Some(foo));
}
```

As-is, the code compiles, which indicates to me that `foo` is indeed something that should work with `impl Fn () -> ()`. However, if I swap out the `None` arm of my `match` with the commented out `None` arm to set `foo` as my "default implentation", I get the following error:

```
error[E0308]: `match` arms have incompatible types
  --> <source>:10:17
   |
6  |   fn bar(baz: Option<impl Fn () -> ()>)
   |                      ---------------- this type parameter
7  |   {
8  |       let func = match baz {
   |  ________________-
9  | |         Some(func) => func,
   | |                       ---- this is found to be of type `impl Fn() -> ()`
10 | |         None => foo,
   | |                 ^^^ expected type parameter `impl Fn() -> ()`, found fn item
11 | |         //None => unimplemented!()
12 | |     };
   | |_____- `match` arms have incompatible types
   |
   = note: expected type `impl Fn() -> ()`
           found fn item `fn() {foo}`

error: aborting due to previous error
```

As far as I can tell from the error, it is saying that `foo` does not qualify as `impl Fn() -> ()` within the function (though it did when passed in as a parameter). What am I missing here that causes this, and is there a way to accomplish what I want here (take an optional closure as a parameter, and use a default function as a closure if none provided)?

Comment: The function signature isn't ideal as the caller has to provide a type for the closure even when passing `None`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the arms of a match statement must resolve to **the exact same type**.

With that in mind, let's replace `impl Fn() -> ()` (which is also the same as `impl Fn()` BTW) with the generics that it represents:

```rust
fn bar<T>(baz: Option<T>) where T: Fn() {
  // ...
}
```

`impl Trait` (in a function parameter) is syntactic sugar for regular generics, so this is "what the compiler sees".

Then let's look at the match:

```rust
fn bar<T>(baz: Option<T>) where T: Fn() {
  let f = match baz {
    Some(f) => f,
    None => foo,
  };
}
```

This can't work, because the type of `foo` is a special thing called a "function item" (essentially a unique type), but the type of `f` is a generic parameter `T`: it could be any type imaginable (as long as it implements `Fn()`). Clearly, these might be different, so Rust rejects the match statement as "having incompatible types".

What you're looking for is a trait object (though this comes at the cost of a heap allocation and vtable dispatch):

```rust
fn bar(baz: Option<impl Fn()>) {
  let f: Box<dyn Fn()> = match baz {
    Some(f) => Box::new(f),
    None => Box::new(foo),
  };

  f();
}
```

Or, you can call the function immediately without storing in a variable:

```rust
fn bar(baz: Option<impl Fn()>) {
  match baz {
    Some(f) => f(),
    None => foo(),
  };
}
```

This is likely to be faster than the `dyn Fn()` approach above, though of course, if you are later storing it in a struct, this will not work.

Comment: Obviously calling the func immediately would make this trivial, but the end goal was to store it in a struct... Thanks.

Comment: Another option that doesn't require boxing would be using an enum like [`Either`](https://docs.rs/either/latest/either/enum.Either.html). This requires you to implement the dynamic dispatch yourself by `match`ing on the enum, but doesn't suffer the indirection penalty that a box does.